# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function optionsframework_options()

Tags: wordpress

i've updated my website with lastest wordpress version but now the Theme Options doesn't work with this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function optionsframework_options() in /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-interface.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-framework.php(209): optionsframework_fields() #1 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): optionsframework_page('') #2 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('appearance_page...') #5 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-admin/themes.php(10): require_once('/home/customer/...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-interface.php on line 25
```

Can you help me to solve it?

EDIT: This is the code inside file:

```
function optionsframework_fields() {

    global $allowedtags;
    $optionsframework_settings = get_option('optionsframework');
    
    // Get the theme name so we can display it up top
    $themename = get_theme_data(STYLESHEETPATH . '/style.css');
    $themename = $themename['Name'];
    
    // Gets the unique option id
    if (isset($optionsframework_settings['id'])) {
        $option_name = $optionsframework_settings['id'];
        
    }
    else {
        $option_name = 'optionsframework';
    };

    $settings = get_option($option_name);
    $options = optionsframework_options();
        
    $counter = 0;
    $menu = '';
    $output = '';
```

Comment: check the php version. do let me know

Comment: i've just checked it and i change it from 7.3 to 7.2, 7.1 and 7.0 but the error is worst

Answer (score 0):

i've just checked it and i change it from 7.3 to 7.2, 7.1 and 7.0 but the error is worst

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function optionsframework_options() in /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-interface.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-framework.php(209): optionsframework_fields() #1 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): optionsframework_page('') #2 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('appearance_page...') #5 /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-admin/themes.php(10): require_once('/home/customer/...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-interface.php on line 27
```

Then  when i set php version to 5.6.40  the error is just

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function optionsframework_options() in /home/customer/www/dimaurorivestimenti.it/public_html/wp-content/themes/Primero/admin/options-interface.php on line 27
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Pixwell Theme. Try to install and activate required plugins first.
I hope this reply saves time for other people having same problem

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pixwell_default_option_values()
```